# (re)mounting the SD card on android emulator

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, sd-card, mount

On the emulator, I can unmount the SD card from the Settings.

I can then mount it on my OS, then unmount it normally.

I haven't been able to figure out how to re-mount it then on the emulator (without rebooting it).

hints:

- the `adb` command `remount` is unrelated: it's about `/system`
- the `emulator` command is unrelated: it's only about starting the emulator
- mounting the SD card in two places of course messing everything up (I tried)

more:

- `mount` outputs the following:

  `/dev/block//vold/179:0 /sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0`
- trying to mount again from the shell after unmounting it, using the same options as above, gives a segfault
- no idea why the double slash in `block//vold`, I guess it's just a typo

Comment: what is the use case for unmounting and mounting the SDCard?

Comment: if you want to access them in a better way then using adb

Comment: and you definitely want to do that if you have an application that creates files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard) suggests that this isn't possible:

> SD Card Emulation
>
> You can create a disk image and then
>   load it to the emulator at startup, to
>   simulate the presence of a user's SD
>   card in the device. To do this, you
>   can use the android tool to create a
>   new SD card image with a new AVD, or
>   you can use the mksdcard utility
>   included in the SDK.
>
> The sections below describe how to
>   create an SD card disk image, how to
>   copy files to it, and how to load it
>   in the emulator at startup.
>
> **Note that you can only load disk image
>   at emulator startup. Similarly, you
>   can not remove a simulated SD card
>   from a running emulator.** However, you
>   can browse, send files to, and
>   copy/remove files from a simulated SD
>   card either with adb or the emulator.
>
> The emulator supports emulated SDHC
>   cards, so you can create an SD card
>   image of any size up to 128 gigabytes.

While Android will unmount the SD card, the emulator process keeps the backing file open.

```
$ ls -go /proc/`pidof emulator`/fd | grep sdcard.img
lrwx------ 1 64 2010-05-13 01:50 10 -> /home/x/.android/avd/WithSD.avd/sdcard.img
```

Someone more familiar with QEMU may be able to provide further insight but, if I were you, I would just try to use NFS to solve this problem.

Comment: Hmm.  I've had no trouble doing this, after unmounting by going to Settings -> SD card -> Unmount.  But I concede I may just have been lucky.

Comment: Note that as of the 4.1.2 System Image, there is no more Settings -> SD card, but Settings -> Storage and there is no more Unmount option, only "Erase SD Card." So that workaround is no longer possible with the Emulator and this must be done on a device.

Answer (score -1):

I tried going to Settings and unmounting the SD card and this worked fine.  Give it a try; remounting it is quite simple.

Doesn't seem like this can be done via adb/cli though.

Comment: I was simply confirming what @telent mentioned above; read the third line, "I haven't been able to figure out how to re-mount it then on the emulator (without rebooting it)." - he seems to indicate he had trouble remounting even within the OS, let alone via adb.

Comment: Exactly: it can't be remounted. Which is what I asked. So what's the point of this answer? *I'm sorry to be rude, really.*