# Disable sdcard in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, sd-card

I just want to know whether is it possible to disable sdcard in my emulator. I don't want to delete my sdcard image file, but I want my emulator to react as if there is no sdcard connected. How to perform this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1)
You can rename the file sdcard.img to whatever.img and restart emulator

2)
You can unmount sdcard within emulator in Settings

3)
You can point emulator to non-existing file with sdcard image
( http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html > Disk Images > -sdcard switch)

4)
You can't unmount SD Card from running emulator
(accroding to best answer on this: [(re)mounting the SD card on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671069/remounting-the-sd-card-on-android-emulator))

5)
In Hardware edit details of Virtual Device (AVD) you can setup "SD Card Support" switch to "no"

Comment: second option is not available since ICS

Answer (score 1):

If you created the AVD image with recommended settings then the **No SDCard** radio button in the AVD Configuration dialog will be disabled.

You can still disable the sdcard by editing the `config.ini` file for the given AVD.

For mac/linux open the config file at `~/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_31.avd/config.ini` (where `Nexus_5_API_31` is the name of the AVD you have), and search and set the following property:

```
hw.sdCard = no
```

Comment: How to find config file -> Go to Device Manager > click on `Down arrow` > `Show on Disk` and in Explorer you can see `config.ini` file. Just click on it and scroll down then you see `hw.sdCard = yes` and make them `hw.sdCard = no`