# Android How to Unmount the Sd Card through Program..?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to safely remove SD card programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632039/how-to-safely-remove-sd-card-programmatically-on-android)

Hi Everyone iam new to android and in my application i got one requirement. My app needs to Unmounting and mouningt the SD Card time to time so please help me is there any way to unmount the SD card Programatically and Mount back using program itself.?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7613783/964741

Comment: I Have asked is there any chance to unmount the SD card through Program

Comment: no it's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632039/how-to-safely-remove-sd-card-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be done. If it were, people could write malicious code to unmount SD card from the phone. Many users store all thier content like songs, videos, photos there. Hence it was a good security decision to not allow apps to unmount SD card, but use them to store data.